# Views no results behaviour remove exposed filter input

Tags: views

I have a view with facet filters and an exposed filter for a keyword search on the title field.

What I want to happen when a user enters a keyword which has no results:

1. The view will post a message saying there were no matches found
2. And then remove the keyword query and return the user to the page state as it was before they entered the keyword.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If the message "there were no matches found" will appear and the keyword query will return to the previous state - where the matches be founded, then the message "no matches found" won't be true. Are you sure you wanna this?